# Factor levels with same names are combined while plotting in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data frame with this structure:

```
> str(pd)
'data.frame':   144 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ Site   : Factor w/ 12 levels "BED","BEU","EB",..: 8 9 10 3 11 1 6 7 5 4 ...
 $ Month  : Factor w/ 12 levels "Dec","Jan","Feb",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Density: int  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 ...
```

I want to change the names of the 12 levels of `Month` from `Dec, Jan, Feb, ..., Nov` to `D, J, F, ..., N` without changing the original dataset before actually plotting with ggplot2.

I tried using `mapvalues()` from the `plyr` package as below:

```
pd$Month2 <- mapvalues(pd$Month , 
                       from = c("Dec","Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov"), 
                       to = c("D","J","F","M","A","M","J","J","A","S","O","N"))
```

Though I get to replace the levels, the 12 levels are reduced to only 8 by combining the months starting with the same letter.

```
> head(pd$Month2)
[1] D D D D D D
Levels: D J F M A S O N
> str(pd$Month2)
 Factor w/ 8 levels "D","J","F","M",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

When I plot this in ggplot2, as expected I get to plot only 8 levels which is wrong in this case

```
ggplot(pd,aes(x=Month2,y=Density,fill=Site))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity",position="dodge", fill= "darkgray")+
  xlab("Month")+ylab("Number of Individuals")+
  facet_wrap(~Site,nrow=3)
```

Months like January, June and July, starting with the same letter J are combined under J just once.

How to plot all the duplicate letters like this separately?

Comment: Why you don't just use the original variable `Dec, Jan, Feb, ...` to plot your data and then just change the x axis labels to show `D, J, F, ...` ? In this case you won't miss any factor levels. Check the examples here: http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_discrete.html especially around the middle of the page that uses `scale_x_discrete("Cut", labels = c("Fair" = "F","Good" = "G",
  "Very Good" = "VG","Perfect" = "P","Ideal" = "I"))`

Comment: @ AntoniosK  Thank you so much for this idea. It worked well.